# How can I get the PCI port type?

Tags: windows-7, windows, pci

Does anybody know how to get a PCI bus speed from the device manager. I have a hardware device, a frame grabber, that must be plugged into the right slots for maximal performance. I am trying to figure out if I have it plugged into the right slot.
[image: Bit Flow Neon]

Answer (score 2):

From the [Intel Datasheet for the X58](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/prodbrief/x58-product-brief.pdf) (found [here](http://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/us/en/chipsets/workstation-chipsets/workstation-chipset-x58.html)) I found this image which seems to suggest that if you have several PCI-e ports, the ones you want to try and use are the ones connected to the X58 chipset rather than the ICH10 as they may be "closer" to the CPU.

[image]

I cannot find anything to tell you what the link speed is in Windows apart from CPU-Z and GPU-z telling you the link speed for graphics cards.

On Linux it appears that `lspci` can tell you the link speed: [How to check how many lanes are used by the PCIe card?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393/how-to-check-how-many-lanes-are-used-by-the-pcie-card)

> `lspci -vv` (run as a superuser) output:
>
> LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, **Width x8**, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-

I cannot find a Windows equivalent, some sources suggest that [WMI](https://superuser.com/questions/97238/windows-equivalent-for-lspci) or SIW *might* work but I think that's a dead end, Googling "WMI Pci-e" gets nothing useful.  I suspect that Windows does not expose the PCI-e link speed for some reason.  I certainly couldn't find anything useful in Device Manager.

Your best bet may be to find out your exact motherboard version and look at the manual to see if they tell you what PCI-e slots work at which speeds.

Comment: @Mikhail One thing you could try would be to get a Linux LiveCD of some description then try the `lspci` trick I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a video card, download gpu-z and it'll tell you what kind of port is being used ny the CARD.

Comment: This isn't a video card, its a special card called a frame grabber which acts like a data hose between a acquisition device and a PC.